# Printing a shifted character set from an array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I'm currently working on a very simple encryption programme, which has the function of printing the alphabet, requesting a key and then printing that same alphabet shifted by the size of the key.

The shifted alphabet is required to be printed below the original.

I've been told that this can be achieved using very basic for loops, but being new to coding, I am unable to achieve the desired outcome. Here is the closest I have come. It only prints ╠ where each shifted letter should be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```c
int main() {
    int n, i, j;

    char alpha[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    printf("Enter Key:");
    scanf_s("%i", &i);

    printf("\n");

    for (n = 0; n < 26; n++) {
        printf("%c ", alpha[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    char encry[100];

    int x = 0;
    for (j = 0; (j < 26); ++j) {
        if (j - i < 0) {
            encry[x] = alpha[26 + (j - i)];
            ++x;
        } else if (j - i >= 0) {
            encry[x] = alpha[j - i];
            ++x;
        }
        printf("%c ", encry[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing x after you set the value but before you print it, which means that you're printing the wrong value:

```c
if (j - i < 0) {
    encry[x] = alpha[26 + (j - i)];
    // no ++x here
} else if (j - i >= 0) {
    encry[x] = alpha[j - i];
    // no ++x here
}
printf("%c ", encry[x]);
// ++x after you print
++x;
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a bunch,this has been annoying me for some time.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just the loop

```
for (n = 0; n < 26; n++) {
    printf("%c ", alpha[( n + i ) % 26]);
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char alpha[] = { "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( alpha ) - 1;
    unsigned int key;

    printf( "Enter Key: " );
    scanf( "%u", &key );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        putchar( alpha[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        putchar( alpha[( i + key ) % N ] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter Key: 13
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ
NOPQRSUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Comment: Wow, I really overcomplicated that.

Comment: If i wanted it to print:

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW

when 3 is entered for the key what would I change? Currently I have to enter 23 to do this.

Comment: @CisNotSoEasyForMe When use as the key the value 26 - 3 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is a working version of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    char alpha[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    printf("Enter Key:");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("\n");

    for (int n = 0; n < 26; n++)
        printf("%c ", alpha[n]);

    printf("\n");

    for (int j = 0; (j < 26); ++j)
        printf("%c ", alpha[(j + i) % 26]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```